# AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values in 0yrs 0mon format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am trying converting date string format to numeric, but  I get some error,
my  date column like this :

```
train['AVERAGE_ACCT_AGE'].head(6)
0     0yrs 0mon
1    1yrs 11mon
2     0yrs 0mon
3     0yrs 8mon
4     0yrs 0mon
5     1yrs 9mon
Name: AVERAGE_ACCT_AGE, dtype: object
```

I tried this code to add DateTime format to that variable.

```
train['AVERAGE_ACCT_AGE']=pd.to_datetime(train['AVERAGE.ACCT.AGE'], format='%Y%m')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name, tz)
    376             try:
--> 377                 values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    378                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-13f5c298f460> in <module>()
----> 1 train['AVERAGE_ACCT_AGE']=pd.to_datetime(train['AVERAGE.ACCT.AGE'], format='%Y-%m')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    449         else:
    450             from pandas import Series
--> 451             values = _convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)
    452             result = Series(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
    453     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, MutableMapping)):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name, tz)
    378                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)
    379             except (ValueError, TypeError):
--> 380                 raise e
    381 
    382     if arg is None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name, tz)
    366                     dayfirst=dayfirst,
    367                     yearfirst=yearfirst,
--> 368                     require_iso8601=require_iso8601
    369                 )
    370 

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

ValueError: time data 0yrs 0mon doesn't match format specified
```

After that, I tried this code to added error ignore to the column.

```
train['AVERAGE_ACCT_AGE']=pd.to_datetime(train['AVERAGE.ACCT.AGE'], format='%Y%m',errors='ignore',infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Its added datetime format then I this code

```
    train['yrs']=train['AVERAGE_ACCT_AGE'].dt.year
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-39b8c6e07f77> in <module>()
----> 1 train['yrs']=train['AVERAGE_ACCT_AGE'].dt.year

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   4366         if (name in self._internal_names_set or name in self._metadata or
   4367                 name in self._accessors):
-> 4368             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   4369         else:
   4370             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py in __get__(self, obj, cls)
    130             # we're accessing the attribute of the class, i.e., Dataset.geo
    131             return self._accessor
--> 132         accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
    133         # Replace the property with the accessor object. Inspired by:
    134         # http://www.pydanny.com/cached-property.html

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\accessors.py in __new__(cls, data)
    323             pass  # we raise an attribute error anyway
    324 
--> 325         raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike "
    326                              "values")
```

please help me how to convert object type to numeric type. I want years and months of columns separately.

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Comment: Numeric? Do you need a column with number of years and another with months or months converted to years in the years column?

Comment: I want years and months of columns separately.

Comment: May help to think about what you actually want. 1 year and 11 months isn't a date, its a length of time. Do you want to keep track of that length? Or get a date that long before the present? Or something else?

Comment: yes,  ArKF I want to   length of time  to present

Answer (score 0):

The column is not of `Datetime` format.

Here is a quick way to get it to numeric. 
I am using more lines than needed.

```
# doing this so we can have it in string format
train['AVERAGE_ACCT_AGE'] = train['AVERAGE_ACCT_AGE'].astype(str)

#Now remove the trailing or any such spaces
train['AVERAGE_ACCT_AGE'] = train['AVERAGE_ACCT_AGE'].map(lambda x: x.strip())

#Next we split and expand the column into 2 columns:
train[['yrs','months']] = train['AVERAGE_ACCT_AGE'].str.split(' ',n=1,expand=True)

#remove characters from new columns, 
#I am assuming the characters remain the same

train['yrs'] = train['yrs'].str.replace('yrs','')
train['months'] = train['months'].str.replace('mon','')
# Convert yrs to float
train['yrs'] = train['yrs'].astype('float')
# Convert months to float
train['months'] = train['yrs'].astype('float')
```

Hope it helps.