# Convert the '10yrs 5mon' categorical value to months

Tags: python, pandas

converting the column to numeric as pre-processing

```
Aging
'10yrs 1mon'
'9yrs 8mon'
'25yrs 5mon'
```

Expected:

```
'10yrs 1mon'     121
'9yrs 8mon'      116
'25yrs 5mon'     305
```

Comment: maybe this could help: https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/ . similiar question asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775743/how-can-i-parse-free-text-time-intervals-in-python-ranging-from-years-to-second

Comment: The solution given below by jezrael is better. Similar/same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765498/attributeerror-can-only-use-dt-accessor-with-datetimelike-values-in-0yrs-0mon/55765835#55765835

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with casting to integers to new `DataFrame` and add new column by multiple `12` first and add second column:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = df['Aging'].str.extract('(\d+)yrs\s+(\d+)mon').astype(int)
df['new'] = df1[0] * 12 + df1[1]
print (df)
          Aging  new
0  '10yrs 1mon'  121
1   '9yrs 8mon'  116
2  '25yrs 5mon'  305
```

Comment: whoa! `pandas` magic! small suggestion: add the `import` statement such that the code is self-contained.